# Xdebug is not running with WAMP

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver, xdebug

My System is

1. Windows 10 with the newest updates
2. Firefox Browser with the newest version
3. Expression Web as developing tool
4. WampServer Version 3.0.6 64bit as web server

I installed xdebug dll like it was mentioned in https://xdebug.org/docs/install.

**php.ini:**

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension=F:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.25\ext\php_xdebug-2.5.0-5.6-vc11-x86_64.dll
```

- I restarted wamp server
- I refreshed wamp server
- I looked in php.ini and found the zend-Logo and this

  > Compiler    MSVC11 (Visual C++ 2012)
  >   ...
  >   This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
  >   Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
  >       with Xdebug v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by Derick Rethans
- I run the test at https://xdebug.org/wizard.php and got

  ```
  Summary
  Xdebug installed: no
  Server API: Command Line Interface
  Windows: yes - Compiler: MS VC11 - Architecture: x64
  Zend Server: no
  PHP Version: 5.6.25
  Zend API nr: 220131226
  PHP API nr: 20131226
  Debug Build: no
  Thread Safe Build: yes
  Configuration File Path: C:\WINDOWS
  Configuration File: F:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.25\php.ini
  Extensions directory: F:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.25\ext
  ```
- I run `php -m` in command line and found no xdebug module

> `[PHP Modules]
>   bcmath
>   bz2
>   calendar
>       calendar
>       Core
>       ctype
>       curl
>       date
>       dom
>       ereg
>       exif
>       fileinfo
>       filter
>       ftp
>       gd
>       gettext
>       gmp
>       hash
>       iconv
>       imap
>       intl
>       json
>       ldap
>       libxml
>       mbstring
>       mcrypt
>       mhash
>       mysql
>       mysqli
>       mysqlnd
>       odbc
>       openssl
>       pcre
>       PDO
>       pdo_mysql
>       pdo_sqlite
>       Phar
>       Reflection
>       session
>       shmop
>       SimpleXML
>       soap
>       sockets
>       SPL
>       sqlite3
>       standard
>       tokenizer
>       wddx
>       xml
>       xmlreader
>       xmlrpc
>       xmlwriter
>       xsl
>       zip
>       zlib
>   [Zend Modules]`

Now I really do not know what went wrong and what I can do to use xdebug.
Looking for some helpful ideas.

Comment: You may be editing wrong php.ini file (you may have one for CLI and one that is used by Apache). For CLI -- show `php --ini` output; For Apache -- show top table of `phpinfo();` output captured via browser.

Comment: WAMPServer comes with XDEBUG already installed !!!!!

Answer (score 8):

WAMPServer comes with XDEBUG already installed. But only in the `php.ini` that is used by Apache.

If you want it available for the PHP CLI then all you have to do is

1. Open the php.ini using `wampmanager->php->php.ini`
2. Go to the bottom of the php.ini file
3. Copy the complete [xdebug] section
4. Edit \wamp\bin\php\php{version}\php.ini (whichever version you are using, or all the versions)
5. Paste the [xdebug] section into the bottom of the file
6. Save php.ini

Then it will also work in the PHP CLI

If you want the latest version of XDEBUG then go here http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/ and download the XDEBUG ADDON `Update xDebug 2.5.0 32 bit x86` or `Update xDebug 2.5.0 64 bit x64` depending on which version of WAMPServer you installed (32 or 64 bit)

You can also download the latest version of WAMPServer `Wampserver update 3.0.8` ADDON while you are there, this just upgrades the WAMPServer control code and not any versions of APACHE,MYSQL or PHP.

But there are also ADDONS available there that will add the latest versions of Apache, Mysql and PHP as well as well as latest versions of phpMyAdmin/Sysinfo and Adminer

I suggest you get rid of whatever version of XDEBUG you downloaded

Comment: Thank you very much indeed for this great help!! I did not know about the php.ini of php. Now the analysis of the Tailored Installation Instructions shows my existing installation and I can go on to find out how to use xdebug. 
Great help!!  



Also many thanks to @LazyOne  
Andreas!!

Comment: Hi RiggsFolly,
sorry but I have to come back again. Following your suggestions brings me to xdebug working. But this is strange: I changed values for xdebug in the section of php.ini from wamp\bin\php\php{version} and nothing happend. If I instead change values in \wamp64\bin\apache\apache{version}\bin the changings applied. I've thought you mentioned to use the \bin\php\php{version}\php.ini to work with? Did I get it the wrong way?
Regards Andreas

Comment: Hi, bit confused. If you have 32bit WAMPServer the main folder is called `\wamp` and if you have 64bit WAMPserver the folder is called `\wamp64`. **Question** Did you put anything to do with WAMPServer onto the Windows PATH?

Comment: Hi, I only use wamp64 and yes the main folder is wamp64. Means also my php folder starts with \wamp64. The whole path is \wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.25. And no, I did not put anything on the windows path.

Comment: Remember, you may have more than one version of PHP installed specially if you have a WAMPServer 3. Make sure you have changed the `php.ini` relating to the PHP version you are running in the CLI

Comment: Man, how did you find that wamp downloads page?  I can't find anything on like that on their website!

Comment: I had to change zend_extension path to make it working

Answer (score 3):

If debugger is still not working make sure that you have xdebug.remote_enable enabled in php.ini file.

Answer (score 0):

Just do below steps

Goto service running greenIcon->Php->php extensions->zend extensions->select installed php_xdebug_version.

After goto php.ini file search [opcache] -> below [opcache] line comment zend_extension.
Save then

restart service.

Answer (score 0):

1- Open the php.ini using wampmanager->php->php.ini

2- Go to the bottom of the php.ini file

3- Edit \wamp\bin\php\php{version}\php.ini (whichever version you are using, or all the versions)

4- Paste the [xdebug] section into the bottom of the file

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="c:/wamp64/bin/php/php8.1.0/zend_ext/php_xdebug-3.1.1-8.1-vs16-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.client_host = "127.0.0.1"
```

5- Save php.ini

6- restarted wamp server